# Need help with height 100% layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build the following layout (file browser type of thing, left block would contain a list of files, right panel would contain selected file content):

```
<------------- MENU ------------------->
<--- LEFT ----><------- RIGHT --------->
<--- LEFT ----><------- RIGHT --------->
<--- LEFT ----><------- RIGHT --------->
<--- LEFT ----><------- RIGHT --------->
<--- LEFT ----><------- RIGHT --------->
<--- LEFT ----><------- RIGHT --------->
```

- The page itself shouldn't have any scrollbars.
- Menu has 100% width and fixed height
- Left block has fixed width and 100% height. If content is taller - scroll bar appears inside the left block only.
- Right block contains `<pre>` element and takes the remaining width and 100% height. If content is wider or taller - scrollbar appears inside the right block only.

**This is what I have so far**: http://jsbin.com/uqegi4/3/edit

The problem is fixed menu height messes up 100% height calculation and all scrollbars inside left and right blocks appear at wrong time.

I don't care about cross browser compatibility, only Chrome matters.

Thanks.

Comment: "only chrome matters" - if only the rest of the internet was like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without JS.

```
<style>

     body, html, div{
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
     }

    .stretch{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
     #container{
        background: #DDD;
        overflow: hidden;
     }
     #menu{
        background: #FF0000;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
     }
     #content{
        top: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #AAA;
     }
     #left{
       background: #00FF00;
       width: 20%;
       overflow: auto;
     }
        #left-content{
          background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
          /* Play with the height to see the scrollbar appear */
          height: 500px;
        }
     #right{
       background: #0000FF;
       width: 80%;
       left: 20%;
       overflow: auto;
     }
        #right-content{
          background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
          /* Play with height and width to see the scrollbars appear */
          height: 1000px;
          width: 3000px;
        }
</style>

<div id="container" class="stretch">
  <div id="menu">Menu</div>
  <div id="content" class="stretch">
    <div id="left" class="stretch">
      <div id="left-content">Left</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="stretch">
      <div id="right-content">Right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Full disclosure: I was actually inspired by JS Bin :)

Comment: Almost, but not quite there. Left container looks fine, but right one doesn't have horizontal nor vertical scrollbars.

Comment: Oops, in #content I declared width:200% instead of width:100%. If you add width: 3000px to #right-content, you should see the horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

100% height is not something that browsers support very well if at all.

i have always reverted to scripting the calculation ie (psuedo code):

onLoad & onResize
 - calc clientHeight
 - minus menu height
 - apply to left and right block

hope that helps.

Comment: As I've said before, whatever CSS can't do, JavaScript can. However, I still think this might be possible in plain CSS...idk

Answer (score 1):

I was working in something similar right now. You need to use Javascript, take a look at this code:

```
    window.onresize = function(event) { resize(); }

    function resize()
    {
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

        var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
        var mainArea = document.getElementById("mainArea");
        sidebar.style.height = (windowHeight - 51) + "px";
        mainArea.style.height = (windowHeight - 51) + "px";
        mainArea.style.width = (windowWidth - 220 - 30) + "px";
    }
```

That code is for an experiment I'm doing it should be improved to remove that numeric constants but that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:
body {height:100%;}
to your CSS. See http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/200.htm

Comment: Doesn't look like it does anything in this case.